# blinking row in wpf datagrid doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, binding, datagrid

I am stuck with an animation in WPF. I need to animate a row(blink) in the datagrid when in that row all checkboxs options are checked(total 3).

```
<DataGrid x:Name="employeesGrid" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedEmployeeIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource dataGridStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">

        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NumberOfSkills}" Value="3">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="blinkingRow">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="true" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="notBlinkingRow">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="true" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            ...

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Skills" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Skills, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SaveChangesCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            ...

    </DataGrid>
```

In view model I have.

```
public int NumberOfSkills 
    {
        get 
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach(Skill skill in ((EmployeeViewModel)SelectedRow).Skills)
            {
                if(skill.IsChecked)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
```

Why this isn't working? I tried a lot of solutions which I finded on the internet, but nothing isn't working. The posted example is very similiar with code on msdn site,so I really don't know what is problem here.

Comment: When do you call PropertyChanged notification for `NumberOfSkills`? It's not in the code you posted, and without it DataGrid won't know it changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems you need to address to fix this issue.

```
get 
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach(Skill skill in ((EmployeeViewModel)SelectedRow).Skills)
    {
        if(skill.IsChecked)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Inside a get of a property you should only return values, and should not change any value. It violates - [Command Query Separation principle][1]

Instead just return private variable _count

```
private int _count
public int NumberOfSkills
{
 get
 {
  return _count;
 }
 set
 {
  _count = value;
  NotifyPropertyChanged("NumberOfSkills")
 }
}
```

Now the question comes where should you set the logic for NumberOfSkills? So you should keep in a place where the user/actor changes it.

Lets say you set `IsChecked` property is set from UI by the user of the class Skills. You can subscribe to IsChecked PropertyChanged() and separate the logic where you update the NumberOfSkills.

```
skill.PropertyChanged += SkillsPropertyChanged

SkillsPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.PropertyName ="IsChecked")
  { 
    //Logic to update the NumberOfSkills
    if(skill.IsChecked)
    {
        NumberOfSkills++;
    }
    else
    {
        NumberOfSkills--;
    }
  }
}
```

The quick and Short Way to do this with your existing approach is simple. Just call `NotifyPropertyChanged("NumberOfSkills")` when you set the `IsCheckedProperty`. Although this might not be straight forward hope you get the idea.

i.e.

```
private bool _isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
 get {return _isChecked;}
 set 
 {
   _isChecked = value;
   NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
   NotifyPropertyChanged("NumberOfSkills");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand where is problem, but my Skill class is serializable so I must create some kind of SkillViewModel and now my code look so dirty. There are a lot of conversion...Model class contains List<Skill>, viewmodel contains ObservableCollection<SkillViewModel> ...